# How do you get an array from json text that has no square brackets in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get data from an api where the result json has no square brackets, and looks like this

```
{
  "status":1,
  "time":42868,
  "response":{
    "some_item":"itemval1",
    "itemstat":"itemstatvalue"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get an array through `json_decode`, but i can't get anywhere I've been trying for hours...

```
$data = json_decode($result);
```

by doing such i get the data back in a large string, but whenever i try to access it such as

```
echo $data->time;
```

or

```
echo $data[0];
```

I get an error saying 500 where my code is invalid, so I'm wondering how I would convert this to an array where i can access these values. Whenever I just `echo $data` though i get a ridiculously large string full of all of the values i need, but can't access them.

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: how would i make this valid json, because I'm getting data from an api and this is the format it returns it in

Comment: Either `"itemval1","itemstat"` need to be contained in square brackets, or `$itemstat` needs to be the value of a different key. I'm afraid I don't really know what you can do about the API returning invalid JSON.

Comment: i misformatted the json when i entered it is it still not possible when you look at the updated formatting

Comment: Yes, it is valid after your edit. But now, it seems `echo $data->time;` should be working. (`echo $data[0];` will _not_ work, because `$data` is an object, and doesn't have a [0] property even if it was an array).

Comment: Not sure what is the problem there... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e905724d84691403718dd62b22a43bf8f6a4147b

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that you are able to `echo $data` and get a large string. `$data` should be an object and `echo` shouldn't really work on it. That should produce a fatal error.

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, check your HTTP server's error log file. The cause will be listed there

Comment: thats what confuses me too @dontpanic i tried vardump but got an error so i used echo and it worked just out of curiosity

Comment: I think you're really missing a [mcve] here. Given the input and the minimal code you've shown, I get the expected result, and I assume others will too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Are you sure you're not using `json_encode` accidentally?

Comment: i think the issue is the json returned does not start and end with a single quote

Answer (score 0):

try the code below. Then, you would be able to understand how json_decode works and how to access the properties.

**[You can see the result here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ea9b2aa77b10410441798508c24ffc4facc4213)**

```
<?php
$s = '{
  "status":1,
  "time":42868,
  "response":{
    "some_item":"itemval1",
    "itemstat":"itemstatvalue"
  }
}';

$object = json_decode($s);

var_dump($object);

echo PHP_EOL . '------------------------' . PHP_EOL;

$array = json_decode($s, true);

var_dump($array);

echo PHP_EOL . '------------------------' . PHP_EOL;

echo $object->response->some_item;

echo PHP_EOL . '------------------------' . PHP_EOL;

echo $array['response']['some_item'];
```

Comment: I deleted my answer and voted to close because this is a duplicate question.  I will ask that you do the same.